# Transformar em função

Tags: php

Tenho este código que traz os dados do usuário no meu banco de dados:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from usuarios where id= {$id}");
$dado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

echo $dado['nome'];
echo $dado['sobrenome'];
```

Como faço para transformar este trecho em uma função?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somente transformando seu trecho de código em funçao:

```
function getUserById ($userId)
{
    $user = new User();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from usuarios where id= {$userId}");
    $dado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    echo $dado['nome']; 
    echo $dado['sobrenome'];
}
```

Ou, se quiser a função com retorno, para reaproveitar o código:

```
function getUserById ($userId)
{
    $user = new User();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from usuarios where id= {$userId}");
    $dado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

    return $dado;
}
//usar a informação retornada:
$user = getUserById("5001");
echo $user['id'];
echo $user['nome'];
echo $user['sobrenome'];
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta @DouglasOak, porém estou utilizando ainda php procedural. Estou criando um sistema para estudo mesmo deste paradigma e depois vou estudar orientação a objetos. Por enquanto estou separando as funções em um arquivo separado. Você teria um exemplo só de transformar essas linhas em uma função?

Comment: Sim, vou editar a resposta

Answer (score 3):

Então, consegui aqui.. Fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
//Função
function dadosUsuario($id, $conexao) {
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from usuarios where id= {$id}");

    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
}
```

e para chamar a função usei:

```
$dado = dadosUsuario($id, $conexao);

echo $dado['cidade'];
echo $dado['estado'];
```

Comment: Curiosamente a sua é a melhor resposta :) Só aprenda formatar melhor. Edite veja as opções de formatação existentes.

Comment: Obrigado @Mineiro

Answer (score 1):

Para criar uma função basta colocar tudo dentro de uma `function`:

```
function bsucarUsuarioId($id) {
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from usuarios where id= {$id}");
$dado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

return echo $dado['nome'] + $dado['sobrenome'];
}
```